# How to prove that integration of exp(-x^2) is error function?

Tags: integration

Prove that $$\int e^{-x^2} dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\rm erf (x).$$

Comment: isn't the error function defined over the integral ?

Comment: [By definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html), $$\text{erf}(x)=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^x\exp(-w^2)\,dw.$$ Is this a different definition than you've been given? Also, since your integral is indefinite, don't forget your constant of integration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing here to prove, the definition of the error function is that

$$
\text{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{-x^2}dx
$$
I suppose that you might be interested in why the $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. Basically, it works like this: let
$$
I = \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx
$$
Now, we can state that
$$\begin{align}
I^2 &= \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2}dy\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta
\end{align}$$
The last line, there, is because we can convert from cartesian to radial coordinates, for which $dxdy = rdrd\theta$ and $r^2=x^2+y^2$. Now, as the inner integral doesn't depend on $\theta$, we may let $r^2=s$ (and so, $rdr=\frac{ds}{2}$) to get
$$\begin{align}
I^2 &= \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-s}\frac{ds}2\\
&= \frac{\pi}{4}\left[-e^{-s}\right]_0^\infty\\
&= \frac{\pi}4
\end{align}$$
Therefore, we have that
$$
I = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}4} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2
$$
Because of this, we have that
$$\begin{align}
\text{erf}(\infty) &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi} \cdot \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\\
&= 1
\end{align}$$
This is the reason for the $\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}$ factor. Hope that helps.